# Trying to create a selection bar for a UITableView in iOS app

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to create a UITableView that has a selection bar that scrolls to whichever row the user has selected (please don't ask why, I just have to do this).  This is different from the typical selection bar that the UITableView has, because there is no animation there.  What I've done is added a TableView in Interface Builder to my main view, and I've also added an imageView to my main view.  I need this to work similar to the selection bar in the UIPickerView except that in this case it is the selection bar that moves.  I figure the code for this would reside inside:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGRect rect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    _imageView.frame = rect;

}
```

Can anyone explain to me how I would code the animation of the selection bar from cell to cell?

Thanks in advance to all who reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the code you currently have works:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        CGRect rect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        _imageView.frame = rect;
    }];
}
```

There is also [+animateWithDuration:animations:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a) and [+animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3adelay%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a)